# gitHubAutoDeployer for Google Cloud Functions auth redirects

Tags: node.js, github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, github-webhook

I'm attempting to use the `gitHubAutoDeployer` function provided by:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/blob/master/tutorials/cloud-functions-github-auto-deployer/index.md

I followed the project, but upon deploying and trying to trigger it, I discovered that the response to my webhook was a Google OAuth screen (in the GitHub project, go to Settings > Webhooks > Recent Deliveries). I went ahead and made the request interactive in a browser so I could provide access. After providing my credentials, I was redirected to the following:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
<h2>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/gitHubAutoDeployer</code> from this server.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

Now, Recent Deliveries in GitHub respond with a 302:

```
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Mon, 30 Mar 2020 15:02:27 GMT
Location: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&amp;passive=true&amp;continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps://us-central1-REDACTED.cloudfunctions.net/gitHubAutoDeployer
Server: Google Frontend
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: d3333e1490ee3ca522c37243673931ed
```

What am I doing wrong? Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:** I opened an issue on the project's GitHub - there's a little more information available over there:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/issues/1202

Answer (score 0):

I also followed the tutorial on the project you referenced and I got the same result.

However, I achieved the expected behavior using [Cloud Build with Continuous deployment](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-functions)